# fullpage.js after first scroll script

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fullpage.js

A question about the Fullpage plugin: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

You can open the site in any section. For example this link opens the site in the fourth section:

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#4thpage

This means the site immediately starts to scroll once you opened the site (it scrolls down to the fourth section).

However, I have a script (it loads a chat box) that slows down this process. Although I added my chat script AFTER the Fullpage.js initialization script, my site first loads the chat box and after that Fullpage scrolls to the right section.

I want the page first to scroll down to the right section on site open, and once the site has opened and has scrolled to the right section, then the chat box script needs to start to run (for as long as the site is open).

How to accomplish that? I tried to place my chat script in the afterLoad and afterRender, but for some reason that makes my chat box not showing up at all. Is there a way to perform some actions after Fullpage has loaded and after the first scroll (on site open) to the right section?

Comment: I think you already have the correct approach when you say that you want to use afterLoad or afterRender to initialize the chat script - this should work in principle. You say that the chat box is not showing up for some reason - you should find out what the reason is.

Can you see any errors in the JavaScript console when you load the page? Have you got a link to your page?

Comment: Thank you @ilokhov. It might be a mistype or something in my codes. Why I thought afterLoad could be a problem, is because that is triggered after each section switch (when you navigate on the page between sections). I don't know if that interferes with the script, since this script needs to be triggered 1 time (when you open the site initially). That's why my second idea was afterRender, but it seems that function doesn't wait for the page to scroll (as explained in the question) or I might be wrong... as soon as I have a sharable link I will publish it here.

Comment: Probably what's taking time is the loading of the JS, CSS or SWF files required for that script to run. Fullpage.js waits until all elements from the site have loaded to scroll to the section. The reason to do this is due to the use of images in section when using `scrollOverflow:true`, as fullpage.js needs to determine if the section needs scroll bar or not depending on the size of the loaded image.

Comment: A good and clarifying explanation, thank you @Alvaro. So what does this mean - I have no choise? Just let Fullpage wait for everything,including this chat script?

Comment: Found a solution: What to write the script to the DOM after section load? But is there also a function for 'after first opened section load'? (so that it doesn't trigger on the next section loads)?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a previous comment:

> Probably what's taking time is the loading of the JS, CSS or SWF files required for that script to run. Fullpage.js waits until all elements from the site have loaded to scroll to the section. The reason to do this is due to the use of images in section when using scrollOverflow:true, as fullpage.js needs to determine if the section needs scroll bar or not depending on the size of the loaded image.

To solve it you can load the element dynamically by using jQuery or ajax.

Otherwise, you can edit fullPage.js and change [line 536](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/jquery.fullPage.js#L536) this:

```
$window.on('load', function() {
    scrollToAnchor();
});
```

To this:

```
scrollToAnchor();
```

The only problem with that is that you'll have to remember to change that line every time you update fullpage.js.

Feel free to open an issue [in fullPage.js github forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues) and a solution might be implement in future versions.

Comment: Your answer was well-meant, but unfortunately when deleting $window.on('load', function() { ... });, and keep only scrollToAnchor();, then the site does not scroll at all and is not able to scroll anymore.
What would be the best way to dynamically load the chat script after scrollToAnchor();.

Comment: I was thinking about something like:
$window.on('load', function() {
    scrollToAnchor();
    myScript();
});
But my script is not loading this way. Anyone with more technical knowledge than me with a solution?

Comment: As I already mentioned in my comment on your original question: can you see any errors in the JavaScript console when you load the page? Have you got a link to your page?

Comment: Thank you @ilokhov. The script shows no error in the Javascript console when I load the page. it's not my intention to make the script faster, although that is also a good idea, but then I would publish another question on Stackoverflow. This question is about how to change the order in Fullpage.js. 1) Firstly scroll to the right section. 2) Secondly load scripts. Your help or from anyone is always appreciated! About a link: This link does exactly the same: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#4thpage It first loads everything and then it scrolls to the page.

Comment: I don't think that example page does the same, because on that page there is no attempt to load anything after fullpage scrolls to page 4. What you need to try to do is add afterLoad as an option when you init the plugin. So it could look something like this (looking at the example link you posted) - afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){ if(anchorLink == '4thpage'){ myScript(); } }. But the problem is, if you don't post the link to a page where you are trying to achieve this, then it's difficult to help you with your specific code.